# Can't open serial connection to device over usb

Tags: arch-linux, usb, tty, serial-port, ttyusb

I'm trying to connect to a serial device over usb with my PC, but whatever I do, it won't succeed.

The device is a STM32 based board.

I'm on arch, my user is in uucp and lock groups. It doesn't matter if I try it with sudo, it still gives the error.

It says I/O error in whatever application I try to open.

For example:

```
# stty -F /dev/ttyACM1    
stty: /dev/ttyACM1: Input/output error
```

Whenever I try to open it, dmesg emits the following line:

`[ +13.632050] cdc_acm 1-4:1.0: acm_port_activate - usb_submit_urb(ctrl irq) failed`

I don't know how to go forward with this, can you please help?

---

additional info:

When I try the same on my laptop, it works perfectly, I don't know what the difference is besides hardware, because they were more-or-less installed the same day, with the same distro, with the same settings.

`lsusb -v -d 1eaf:0004`:

```
Frame 203273: 64 bytes on wire (512 bits), 64 bytes captured (512 bits) on interface usbmon1, id 0
    Interface id: 0 (usbmon1)
        Interface name: usbmon1
    Encapsulation type: USB packets with Linux header and padding (115)
    Arrival Time: Apr 24, 2021 23:02:48.009074000 CEST
    [Time shift for this packet: 0.000000000 seconds]
    Epoch Time: 1619298168.009074000 seconds
    [Time delta from previous captured frame: 0.001224000 seconds]
    [Time delta from previous displayed frame: 199.923870000 seconds]
    [Time since reference or first frame: 5102.916738000 seconds]
    Frame Number: 203273
    Frame Length: 64 bytes (512 bits)
    Capture Length: 64 bytes (512 bits)
    [Frame is marked: False]
    [Frame is ignored: False]
    [Protocols in frame: usb]
USB URB
    [Source: host]
    [Destination: 1.27.2]
    URB id: 0xffff9e5a096db840
    URB type: URB_SUBMIT ('S')
    URB transfer type: URB_INTERRUPT (0x01)
    Endpoint: 0x82, Direction: IN
    Device: 27
    URB bus id: 1
    Device setup request: not relevant ('-')
    Data: not present ('<')
    URB sec: 1619298168
    URB usec: 9074
    URB status: Operation now in progress (-EINPROGRESS) (-115)
    URB length [bytes]: 64
    Data length [bytes]: 0
    [Response in: 203274]
    [bInterfaceClass: Communications and CDC Control (0x02)]
    Unused Setup Header
    Interval: 128
    Start frame: 0
    Copy of Transfer Flags: 0x00000204, No transfer DMA map, Dir IN
    Number of ISO descriptors: 0

Bus 001 Device 027: ID 1eaf:0004 Leaflabs Maple serial interface
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass            2 Communications
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         0 
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  idVendor           0x1eaf Leaflabs
  idProduct          0x0004 Maple serial interface
  bcdDevice            2.00
  iManufacturer           1 LeafLabs
  iProduct                2 Maple
  iSerial                 0 
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength       0x0043
    bNumInterfaces          2
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0 
    bmAttributes         0xc0
      Self Powered
    MaxPower              100mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass         2 Communications
      bInterfaceSubClass      2 Abstract (modem)
      bInterfaceProtocol      1 AT-commands (v.25ter)
      iInterface              0 
      CDC Header:
        bcdCDC               10.01
      CDC Call Management:
        bmCapabilities       0x03
          call management
          use DataInterface
        bDataInterface          1
      CDC ACM:
        bmCapabilities       0x06
          sends break
          line coding and serial state
      CDC Union:
        bMasterInterface        0
        bSlaveInterface         1 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x82  EP 2 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0040  1x 64 bytes
        bInterval             255
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        1
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           2
      bInterfaceClass        10 CDC Data
      bInterfaceSubClass      0 
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 
      iInterface              0 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x03  EP 3 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0040  1x 64 bytes
        bInterval               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0040  1x 64 bytes
        bInterval               0
can't get device qualifier: Resource temporarily unavailable
can't get debug descriptor: Resource temporarily unavailable
Device Status:     0x0000
  (Bus Powered)
```

`dmesg -wH`:

```
[  +2.391790] usb 1-4: new full-speed USB device number 27 using xhci_hcd
[  +0.181105] usb 1-4: New USB device found, idVendor=1eaf, idProduct=0004, bcdDevice= 2.00
[  +0.000004] usb 1-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[  +0.000002] usb 1-4: Product: Maple
[  +0.000001] usb 1-4: Manufacturer: LeafLabs
[  +0.000370] cdc_acm 1-4:1.0: ttyACM1: USB ACM device
[  +0.000198] usbcore: registered new interface driver cdc_acm
[  +0.000002] cdc_acm: USB Abstract Control Model driver for USB modems and ISDN adapters
```

usbmon with Wireshark:

```
Frame 203273: 64 bytes on wire (512 bits), 64 bytes captured (512 bits) on interface usbmon1, id 0
    Interface id: 0 (usbmon1)
        Interface name: usbmon1
    Encapsulation type: USB packets with Linux header and padding (115)
    Arrival Time: Apr 24, 2021 23:02:48.009074000 CEST
    [Time shift for this packet: 0.000000000 seconds]
    Epoch Time: 1619298168.009074000 seconds
    [Time delta from previous captured frame: 0.001224000 seconds]
    [Time delta from previous displayed frame: 199.923870000 seconds]
    [Time since reference or first frame: 5102.916738000 seconds]
    Frame Number: 203273
    Frame Length: 64 bytes (512 bits)
    Capture Length: 64 bytes (512 bits)
    [Frame is marked: False]
    [Frame is ignored: False]
    [Protocols in frame: usb]
USB URB
    [Source: host]
    [Destination: 1.27.2]
    URB id: 0xffff9e5a096db840
    URB type: URB_SUBMIT ('S')
    URB transfer type: URB_INTERRUPT (0x01)
    Endpoint: 0x82, Direction: IN
    Device: 27
    URB bus id: 1
    Device setup request: not relevant ('-')
    Data: not present ('<')
    URB sec: 1619298168
    URB usec: 9074
    URB status: Operation now in progress (-EINPROGRESS) (-115)
    URB length [bytes]: 64
    Data length [bytes]: 0
    [Response in: 203274]
    [bInterfaceClass: Communications and CDC Control (0x02)]
    Unused Setup Header
    Interval: 128
    Start frame: 0
    Copy of Transfer Flags: 0x00000204, No transfer DMA map, Dir IN
    Number of ISO descriptors: 0


Frame 203274: 64 bytes on wire (512 bits), 64 bytes captured (512 bits) on interface usbmon1, id 0
    Interface id: 0 (usbmon1)
        Interface name: usbmon1
    Encapsulation type: USB packets with Linux header and padding (115)
    Arrival Time: Apr 24, 2021 23:02:48.009078000 CEST
    [Time shift for this packet: 0.000000000 seconds]
    Epoch Time: 1619298168.009078000 seconds
    [Time delta from previous captured frame: 0.000004000 seconds]
    [Time delta from previous displayed frame: 0.000004000 seconds]
    [Time since reference or first frame: 5102.916742000 seconds]
    Frame Number: 203274
    Frame Length: 64 bytes (512 bits)
    Capture Length: 64 bytes (512 bits)
    [Frame is marked: False]
    [Frame is ignored: False]
    [Protocols in frame: usb]
USB URB
    [Source: 1.27.2]
    [Destination: host]
    URB id: 0xffff9e5a096db840
    URB type: URB_ERROR ('E')
    URB transfer type: URB_INTERRUPT (0x01)
    Endpoint: 0x82, Direction: IN
    Device: 27
    URB bus id: 1
    Device setup request: not relevant ('-')
    Data: not present ('E')
    URB sec: 1619298168
    URB usec: 9078
    URB status: Operation not permitted (-EPERM) (-1)
    URB length [bytes]: 0
    Data length [bytes]: 0
    [Request in: 203273]
    [Time from request: 0.000004000 seconds]
    [bInterfaceClass: Communications and CDC Control (0x02)]
    Unused Setup Header
    Interval: 0
    Start frame: 0
    Copy of Transfer Flags: 0x00000000
    Number of ISO descriptors: 0
```

Comment: This is a known bug, see here for more information and detailed progress: https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/70593?only_watched=1&type%5B0%5D=&sev%5B0%5D=&due%5B0%5D=&cat%5B0%5D=&status%5B0%5D=open&percent%5B0%5D=&reported%5B0%5D=

Comment: Thank you very much @domochevski, it seems that it is indeed the same problem I'm having. I'll either try to compile myself a cherry pick of that commit, or just wait for it to be in stable.

Comment: Well for anyone interested, this bug has been fixed in the linux 5.12.1-arch1-1 kernel.